# How can I schedule code to run every few hours in Elixir or Phoenix framework?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So let's say I want to send a bunch of emails or recreate sitemap or whatever every 4 hours, how would I do that in Phoenix or just with Elixir?

Answer (score 490, accepted):

There is a simple alternative that does not require any external dependencies:

```ex
defmodule MyApp.Periodically do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(_opts) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{})
  end

  def init(state) do
    schedule_work() # Schedule work to be performed at some point
    {:ok, state}
  end

  def handle_info(:work, state) do
    # Do the work you desire here
    schedule_work() # Reschedule once more
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  defp schedule_work() do
    Process.send_after(self(), :work, 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000) # In 2 hours
  end
end
```

Now in your supervision tree:

```ex
children = [
  MyApp.Periodically
]

Supervisor.start_link(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
```

Comment: It's impossible not to love this language :)

Comment: Where should I put this file? Under lib/ directory of Phoenix project? Where do the test go, to test/periodically/*?

Comment: In lib because it is a long running process. You can put the test whatever makes sense, maybe "test/my_app/periodically_test.exs".

Comment: Any particular reason to not move `Process.send_after` into its own function so that the function can be called from both `init` and `handle_info`?

Comment: Or not to do `:timer.send_interval`?

Comment: @CodyPoll `:timer.send_interval` is fine but keep in mind that the intervals will constant. So imagine you want to do something every minute and, in the future, the work itself takes more than a minute. In such cases, you'd be working all the time and your message queue would grow unbounded. The solution above will always wait the given period *after* the work is done.

Comment: @JoséValim Just found this question. Is there any explanation, why the message from Process.send_after should be handled by handle_info? Didn't find any mentions in official doc.

Comment: @StanislavMekhonoshin it is how GenServers work behind the scenes. When it receives messages that were not sent with call nor cast, they are handled by `handle_info/2`.

Comment: @JoséValim thanks! we already discussed it at elixir issues on github :)

Comment: The drawback to using GenServer alone is that all of your scheduled jobs will be lost if your application crashes. That's why there are so many libraries dealing with this problem - most of the time you need resiliency against losing scheduled tasks.

Comment: Applications don't crash, processes crash. You shouldn't have the state critical to the work in the process where the scheduling is done.

Comment: In case anybody gets stuck, like me, don't use a float in your interval math. I was using `0.25`. This produces an argument error from `:erlang.send_after`. The error messages shows the arguments to `:erlang.send_after` in a different order than given to `Process.send_after`, which threw me off for a while.

Comment: addressing the crash possibility raised by @sheldonkreger: persist the time of your last execution in ets or a disk persistence layer, and query that during `init`, computing your first delay.

Comment: It is also highly dependent on the task. Most tasks won't cause an issue if they end-up running twice in a row.

Comment: If this task is going to be run every 2 hours would hibernating the genserver between tasks help?

Comment: @JoséValim I've written a lib to extend your code with cron-like syntax and support for multiple nodes running distributed: https://github.com/loopsocial/ex_scheduler.

Comment: @JoséValim — Is the `{MyApp.Periodically, []}` construct a preferred equivalent to `worker(MyApp.Periodically, [])` in Elixir these days? Trying to find docs to confirm this but having trouble this morning. Absolutely love this example btw — very instructive. Playing around with it and having fun with using `:continue` etc.

Answer (score 45):

[Quantum](https://github.com/quantum-elixir/quantum-core) lets you create, find and delete jobs at runtime.

Furthermore, you can pass arguments to the task function when creating a cronjob, and even modify the timezone if you're not happy with UTC.

If your app is running as multiple isolated instances (e.g. Heroku), there are job processors backed by PostgreSQL or Redis, that also support task scheduling:

Oban: https://github.com/sorentwo/oban

Exq: https://github.com/akira/exq

Toniq: https://github.com/joakimk/toniq

Verk: https://github.com/edgurgel/verk

Comment: I think it will be an overkill for a lot of simple tasks that don't require it but thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: Having a list of libraries available was helpful for me.

Answer (score 25):

You can use [erlcron](https://github.com/erlware/erlcron) for that. You use it like

```
job = {{:weekly, :thu, {2, :am}},
  {:io, :fwrite, ["It's 2 Thursday morning~n"]}}

:erlcron.cron(job)
```

A `job` is a 2-element tuple. The first element is a tuple that represents the schedule for the job and the second element is the function or an MFA(Module, Function, Arity). In the above example, we run `:io.fwrite("It's 2 Thursday morning")` every 2am of Thursday.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yeah it's better than nothing, thank you. I will leave the question unanswered for a while, maybe there will be other suggestions

Comment: You're welcome! There's also https://github.com/c-rack/quantum-elixir which is an elixir lib, if you prefer

Answer (score 8):

I used Quantum library [Quantum- Elixir](https://github.com/c-rack/quantum-elixir).
Follow below instructions.

```ex
#your_app/mix.exs
defp deps do
  [{:quantum, ">= 1.9.1"},  
  #rest code
end



#your_app/mix.exs
def application do
  [mod: {AppName, []},
   applications: [:quantum,
   #rest code         
 ]]
end

#your_app/config/dev.exs
config :quantum, :your_app, cron: [
  # Every minute
  "* * * * *": fn -> IO.puts("Hello QUANTUM!") end
]
```

All set. Start the server by running below command.

```ex
iex -S mix phoenix.server
```

Comment: This is like cronjobs

Answer (score 6):

I find [`:timer.send_interval/2`](https://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#send_interval-2) slightly more ergonomic to use with a `GenServer` than `Process.send_after/4` (used in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32097971/1417451)).

Instead of having to reschedule your notification each time you handle it, `:timer.send_interval/2` sets up an interval on which you receive a message endlessly—no need to keep calling `schedule_work()` like the accepted answer uses.

```
defmodule CountingServer do
  use GenServer

  def init(_) do
    :timer.send_interval(1000, :update)
    {:ok, 1}
  end

  def handle_info(:update, count) do
    IO.puts(count)
    {:noreply, count + 1}
  end
end
```

Every 1000 ms (i.e., once a second), `IntervalServer.handle_info/2` will be called, print the current `count`, and update the GenServer's state (`count + 1`), giving you output like:

```
1
2
3
4
[etc.]
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that this solution can lead to an overflowing queue if your interval is smaller than the time it takes to finish the task.

Answer (score 1):

Besides to use `Process.send_after`, you can also use [:timer.apply_interval](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html#apply_interval-4).

Answer (score 1):

Normally we use [Oban](https://hexdocs.pm/oban/Oban.html) for this but it depends on the priority of the tasks.
If you just want to run a job that should be running after a specific period of time. then you can also use `Genserver`.

[Genservers](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/GenServer.html) start as our application is started. you can use periodic processes `Process.send_after(self(), :work, time)` and add `handle_info` to handle the work you want to do. I used this when i needed to add long polling to my project.

Answer (score 0):

[Quantum](https://github.com/c-rack/quantum-elixir) is great, we use it at work as a cron replacement with a phoenix front-end and we also add jobs in [real-time](https://github.com/sickill/quantum-elixir/blob/master/pages/runtime.md) which is very neat.

Answer (score 0):

Crontab lib & :timer, send_after , GenState machine or GenServer.

Generally we define cron expression in elixir module, and later parsed in that module during init.
https://hexdocs.pm/crontab/readme.html

we schedule a timer using this.
`Process.send_after(self(), :message, time)`
or `:timer.send_interval/2`
It returns timer ref, which can be stored in state, which can also be cancelled by the ref.

Answer (score 0):

I built a little macro upon the accepted answer, maybe it'll be helpful for someone. (It could use some improvements, but works fine - I use it with @loop_time quite often)

```
defmodule Listener do
  @callback perform_work() :: any()

  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote location: :keep, bind_quoted: [opts: opts] do
      @behaviour Listener
      @at_minute Module.get_attribute(__MODULE__, :at_minute, nil)
      @at_hour Module.get_attribute(__MODULE__, :at_hour, nil)
      @loop_time Module.get_attribute(__MODULE__, :loop_time, nil)

      require Logger
      use GenServer

      # ************************************************************
      # API
      # ************************************************************

      def start_link(_) do
        Logger.info("Starting #{__MODULE__} ...")
        GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, nil, name: __MODULE__)
      end

      def stop(_) do
        Logger.info("Stopping #{__MODULE__} ... ")
        GenServer.stop(nil)
      end

      # ************************************************************
      # Callbacks
      # ************************************************************

      def init(_) do
        schedule_work()
        {:ok, nil}
      end

      def handle_info(:work, _) do
        perform_work()
        schedule_work()
        {:noreply, nil}
      end

      # ************************************************************
      # PRIVATE
      # ************************************************************

      defp schedule_work() do
        calc_loop_time = calculate_loop_time()
        Process.send_after(self(), :work, calc_loop_time)
      end

      defp calculate_loop_time() do
        if @loop_time != nil do
          @loop_time
        else
          datetime_now = DateTime.utc_now()
          time_now = Time.utc_now()

          date_today = Date.utc_today()
          date_next_day = Date.add(date_today, 1)

          {:ok, time_to_run} = Time.new(@at_hour, @at_minute, 0)

          case Time.compare(time_to_run, time_now) do
            :gt ->
              {:ok, datetime_to_run} = DateTime.new(date_today, time_to_run)
              DateTime.diff(datetime_to_run, datetime_now, :millisecond)

            :lt ->
              {:ok, datetime_to_run} = DateTime.new(date_next_day, time_to_run)
              DateTime.diff(datetime_to_run, datetime_now, :millisecond)

            :eq ->
              0
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
defmodule MacroTest.TestListener do
  @at_hour 13
  @at_minute 10

  use Listener

  def perform_work() do
    IO.puts("Hello from TestListener")
  end
end
```