# How to use Elixir OTP Supervisor/GenServer for quick jobs

Tags: elixir

I don't want to have a long running process. But at the same time, want to use Supervisor, and worker processes. How should I go about it?

Scenario: Every midnight I fetch data from an external API using  supervised processes.

But I don't want the process to run until next day if the workers complete their job.

In my case, 1 Supervisor, 5 poolboy processes always exist.

Since the erlang processes are cheap, and these are idle, should I have the supervisor part of my `applications` and start every time, and leave it idle?

Or should I try to kill the Supervisor when the worker processes are done?

When I do `:observer.start` I could see few of my dependency packages have processes started. Is this okay? When should I worry about the number of processes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few processes really isn't a big deal. For one application I worked on, we tested starting it up with a few million poolboy processes, and it only took a little over 1GB of RAM to do so. According to [the docs](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/processes.html):

```
A newly spawned Erlang process uses 309 words of memory in the non-SMP emulator without HiPE support. (SMP support and HiPE support both add to this size.)
```

So really, don't worry about dependencies spawning too many processes. It's not a big deal.

As for your structural question, one possibility is to use a [simple_one_for_one](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/sup_princ.html#simple) supervisor. You then just have a cron job that sends a message (perhaps a cURL POST request if you have a web server going) to the running VM to execute whatever your batch job is, or use the [timer module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/timer.html)to run jobs at specified intervals.

EDIT: Elixir has similar functionality in the [Process module](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Process.html#send_after/3). See Jose Valim's answer to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085258/how-to-run-some-code-every-few-hours-in-phoenix-framework).

However you choose to start your job, you can them simply call [supervisor:start_child](http://erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_child-2) or [Supervisor.start_child](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Supervisor.html#start_child/2), depending on which language you're working in, to start a worker for your job.