# Phoenix Background Job

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am new to Phoenix and Elixir. I want to add to Chat app a background job that should run once a minute, get data from another server and broadcast it to rooms.
How can I do something like this in Phoenix?

Comment: A simple way to run background job periodically - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085258/how-to-run-some-code-every-few-hours-in-phoenix-framework Broadcasting - https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Channel.html#broadcast/3

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just another question, where in code i have to start a job, and how can i pass socket to it ?

Comment: You can use `MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast` (documented about half way down on https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html) to broadcast to a channel.

Comment: @JustMichael you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to implement background jobs was offered by Jose Valim [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085258/how-to-run-some-code-every-few-hours-in-phoenix-framework).

And for broadcasting, you can use `MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast()` as Gazler pointed out in the comments.