# Cron tasks quantum elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, cron-task

I want to execute a code every minute and I tried an attempt using the following code:

```
#your_app/mix.exs
defp deps do
    [{:quantum, ">= 1.9.1"},    
     #rest code
  end



#your_app/mix.exs
def application do
    [mod: {AppName, []},
     applications: [:quantum,
     #rest code         
   ]]
  end

#your_app/config/dev.exs
config :quantum, :your_app, cron: [
    # Every minute
    "* * * * *": fn -> IO.puts("Hello QUANTUM!") end
]
```

This is the one of the answers to this question [How to run some code every few hours in Phoenix framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32085258/5764295][this])

However, when I execute iex -S mix it doesn't show any message, neither an error message.

Do you know what the problem would be?

Comment: Are you on quantum 2.0.0? Looks like they changed their API significantly in v2. See https://hexdocs.pm/quantum/migrate-v2.html and https://hexdocs.pm/quantum/readme.html. They have the updated instructions there.

Comment: Yes, I'am using quantum 2.0.0, I also tried what the documentation says but it's still not working.

Answer (score 3):

The answer that you referred must be outdated. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/c-rack/quantum-elixir) you need to create your own scheduler:

```
defmodule YourApp.Scheduler do
  use Quantum.Scheduler, otp_app: :your_app
end
```

Start it as a worker in **lib/your_app.ex**

```
children = [
  supervisor(YourApp.Repo, []),
  supervisor(YourApp.Endpoint, []),
  ...
  worker(YourApp.Scheduler, [])
]
```

And configure in **config/dev.exs** using the following format:

```
config :test, YourApp.Scheduler, jobs: [
  # Every minute
  {"* * * * *", fn -> IO.puts("Hello QUANTUM!") end}
]
```

Comment: It worked when I added the worker to **lib/your_app.ex**

Comment: sorry, I named my app `test`, but for the answer I changed every `Test` and `test` to `YourApp` and `your_app`. Seems like not everywhere, fixed.