# Scheduling tasks in Quasar, without spawning a new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, quasar

I'd like to spawn many Actors which execute a private method at a specific time interval. This task will need to run at the time interval indefinitely until the Actor is terminated.

All of the solutions I've seen in Java involve creating a new thread, for example Spring's [TaskExecutor](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) or using [ScheduledExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7814149/1289597). Because an Actor already has its own Fiber, I see no reason to spawn a thread unless my task is very heavy.

In Elixir, this was very simple to achieve using [Process.send_after()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32097971/1289597).

Is there a similar way to do this in Java using Quasar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiber has method `sleep(long millis)`, so you can easily create a fiber which executes periodically with:

```
while (!end) {
    doTask();
    sleep(period);
}
```